# run tomcat server on lan

Tags: tomcat6

I am running a server on Windows XP SP2 computer . Lets call it computer_1. The ip address of computer is 192.168.1.2

Now I have another computer ( computer_2) on the lan with ip address 192.168.1.3

I want to access the site on computer_1 from computer_2.

comupter_2 can ping computer_1 (ping 192.168.1.2 works)

But when I type http://192.168.1.2 in the browser of computer_2, nothing happens.

I want to access the site on comupter_1 from computer_2

Please help.

Comment: What happens when you type http://192.168.1.2 in the browser of computer_1?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a default configuration of Tomcat it is probably running on port 8080. So you will need to type http://192.168.1.2:8080

Don't forget the http:// part or MSIE will choke ;-)

Cheers, André